# <figure> images won't show sometimes in android

Tags: android, css, figure

Primary: when I load my webpage (with 9 images) sometime the images are not loaded at all, sometime they do. Sometimes only some and others not at all.

Secondary: the images are completely filled in the div (like 100%) while expecting 33%.

I use the default Android browser on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 10.1 (firefox and chrome do work flawless). The tablet is using Android 4.2.2

When I replace this piece of code in my webpage:

```
<figure class="maxRight33">
<img src="/img/picture.png" />
</figure>
```

With this:

```
<div class="maxRight33">
<img src="/img/sharp-cv-p09fr-s.png" />
</div>
```

Then it all works ok. But I like to use  because of a certain reasong, not div.
Are there issues or so with this webbrowser?

This is the css code:

```
.maxRight33 {max-width:33%;float:right;margin-left:1rem}
img {max-width:100%;height:auto;border:0}
figure {display:table}
figure img {display:block;width:100%;}
```

Comment: It may have something to do with the line `figure {display:table}`. This should be used to mimic a tabular layout, and used in conjunction with table-row and table-cell in child items. It just doesn't look like it belongs. Try taking that out.

Comment: This tabular layout was the only solution I could find (and that did work) for captions of the figure if the caption is broader than the image and it should stay below the image. Indeed I should mention that in CSS there is this line too

    figcaption {display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;text-align:center;margin-top:.5rem} 
BUT... on this problamitc page I don't use those figcaptions, but on other pages I do and there more weird things happen (only in the default browser, FF and chrome work flawless, but I thought let's start with asking for this problem)...